# Issue with my function in my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to switch from a very basic webpage into anthor one but i face some issues with the result once i click on `getAll`

My previous webpage (the wroking one )

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getAll()"> Get All The Users </button>

    <div id="users"></div>

    <script>
        function getAll()
        
        {
            $("#users").html("");
            
            
        
            $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/users",  function(data)
            {
                for (var i in data) {
                    $('#users').append("<p>ID: " + data[i].id + "</p>")
                    $('#users').append("<p>First name: " + data[i].fname + "</p>")
                    $('#users').append("<p>Last name: " + data[i].lname + "</p><br>")
                }
            }); 
            
        }
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getAll is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (testt.html:96)
onclick @ @ testt.html:96
testt.html:145 

Uncaught ReferenceError: screenfull is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (testt.html:145)
(anonymous) @ testt.html:145
```

**EDITED**
After Nina´s answer i get the desired result but the homepage looks like this:

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IST0A.png)

So it distorts the upper part of my homepage.

Comment: _“getAll is not defined”_ - when you’re using “old-school” event handling via HTML attributes, the function must exist _before_ that element occurs in the DOM. But since you are using jQuery already, you should rather deal with the button click event the jQuery way, too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
<div id="requestfs">/div>
```

to

```
<div id="requestfs"></div>
```

---

And you need to change this line

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/users" ,  function(data[i])
//                                                      ^^^
```

to (without index)

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/users" ,  function(data)
```

---

At least you need to include the library somewhere, before using it.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Optional you could use the type attribute as well

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: text/javascript is assumed if not specified. There's no need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function, the `{` should be on the same line with the `function` keyword. For example:

```
function foo() {

}
```

You should change all of those(note, they are on line 110 and line 20).

---

Next, in the line

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/users" ,  function(data[i]) {
```

`function (data[i])` should be `function (data)`

---

Also, remember to include the jquery library.

Comment: _“When you declare a function, the { should be on the same line with the function keyword”_ - that’s only a coding convention, but has nothing to do with the problem itself. Both variants are valid JS.

Comment: Well, it has an exception, if you use the `return` keyword to return an object, it will cause an error(and it is very hard to find). It is a good coding practice. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taaEzHI9xyY&list=PL62E185BB8577B63D&index=14 at 19:58.